# postgresql - pg_basebackup-- could not get COPY data stream -- requested WAL segment has already been removed

Tags: postgresql

while doing a backup of postgresql 14.5. getting error:
pg_basebackup-- could not get COPY data stream
requested WAL segment xxxx has already been removed

whats the cause of this and how to fix it so i can do the backup.

there was a post about increasing the wal_keep_segments, but the conf file did not have that variable, and when i add it to the conf file, the db did not start up.

Thanks.

pg_basebackup -P -Xf -Ft -z -R

** finally get it to work, they change wal_keep_segments to wal_keep_size.

Comment: Do you have a configured archive backup on the source database?

Comment: are you referring to master-slave? we do not have that.

Comment: are you referring to master-slave? we do not have that.  
just to be sure, how to i check if have master slave?

Comment: pg_basebackup has a lot of options.  What ones are you using?

Answer (score 0):

When calling `pg_basebackup`, don't use `--wal-method=fetch`. Use `--wal-method=stream` instead.

Comment: is the stream option set in the configure file?

Comment: No, on the command line.